# How to use serializer result as queryset on another serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is possible to create a dependence between serializers, like the code below?

```
class ProSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False,queryset=Entity.objects.all())
    foo = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,queryset=Foo.objects.filter(entity=entity))
    class Meta:
        model = ..............
```

What I want to do is to limit the queryset on Foo to just the ones from the chosen entity. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Rest Framework does not make this easy, at least in version 2.x – and I am not sure whether there are/were any plans to make it better in version 3.

I hacked this fixed in various places with try catches in serializer inits filtering any applicable field's queryset by the parent property passed in the data dictionary before making an attempt at standardising the problem – the following is what I came up with.

**SlugRelatedDependentField**

```
class SlugRelatedDependentField(SlugRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, depends_on=None, **kwargs):
        assert depends_on is not None, 'The `depends_on` argument is required.'

        self.depends_on       = depends_on # archive_unit__organization or organization
        self.depends_segments = self.depends_on.split('__')
        self.depends_parent   = self.depends_segments.pop(0)
        self.depends_field    = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: self.parent.parent.fields[self.depends_parent])
        self.depends_queryset = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: self.depends_field.queryset)
        self.depends_model    = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: self.depends_queryset.model)

        super(SlugRelatedDependentField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def contextualize(self, instance, data):
        self.data = data
        self.instance = instance

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            return self.queryset.filter(**{self.depends_on: reduce(getattr, self.depends_segments, self.get_relation())})
        except self.depends_model.DoesNotExist:
            # if parent was absent or invalid, empty the queryset
            return self.queryset.none()
        except TypeError:
            # if parent was a Page instance, use the full queryset, it's only a list view
            return self.queryset.all()

    def get_relation(self):
        try:
            # if an allowed parent was passed, filter by it
            return self.depends_queryset.get(**{self.depends_field.slug_field: self.data[self.depends_parent]})
        except (KeyError, TypeError):
            # if data was empty or no parent was passed, try and grab it off of the model instance
            if isinstance(self.instance, self.parent.parent.Meta.model):
                return getattr(self.instance, self.depends_parent)
            elif self.instance is None:
                raise self.depends_model.DoesNotExist
            else:
                raise TypeError
```

**Usage**

```
class RepositorySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    organization = SlugRelatedField(queryset=Organization.objects.all(), slug_field='slug')
    teams = SlugRelatedDependentField(allow_null=True, depends_on='organization', many=True, queryset=Team.objects.all(), required=False, slug_field='slug')

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
        f = self.fields['teams']

        # assign instance and data for get_queryset
        f.child_relation.contextualize(instance, data)

        # inject relation values from instance if they were omitted so they are validated regardless
        if data is not empty and instance and name not in data:
            data[name] = [getattr(relation, f.child_relation.slug_field) for relation in getattr(instance, name).all()]

        super(RepositorySerializer, self).__init__(instance=instance, data=data, **kwargs)
```

**Summary**

`SlugRelatedDependentField` expands on the regular `SlugRelatedField` to accept a `depends_on` kwarg which accepts a string describing the field's relation to another – in this example, the usage describes that the teams assigned to this repository must belong to the organization.

**A few gotchas**

- I empty the queryset with `.none()` if the parent does not exist, this avoids choice leak, which may be otherwise exposed via `OPTIIONS` requests and validation messages, and is usually undesirable.
- I used `data` when querying for the parent record, IIRC the reason I did this was because `data` is consistently available whilst the parent field's object may not be e.g. in the case of `PATCH` requests.
- You'll notice I inject any omitted relation values in the latter portion of the serializer init, this serves the purpose of forcing validation to run on the many field – useful e.g. if the user changed the `organization` of the record in a `PATCH` request, meaning the assigned `teams` no longer apply.

**Support for distant relations**

Another problem this solution caters for is referencing distant relations, this can be done by passing a `__` delimited string to `depends_on` e.g. `repository__organization`, I don't have a great example use case for this, but it's there if you need it.

Comment: What is `name` and how are you using `empty`?  I can't tell if these are typos because neither are referenced.